# Автоматическая конвертация текста в другую раскладку в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Часто бывает так что печатаешь не на той раскладке клавиатуры, потом приходится удалять и писать на нужной. Есть ли в phpshtorm хоткей который конвертирует фразу в нужную раскладку?

Comment: Такого нет. Используйте Punto Switcher или аналоги, или осваивайте 10-пальцевый слепой метод печати.

Answer (score 1):

В phpshtorm не припомню. Да и нет смысла ПО, которое специализируется на конкретной области делать плагины или вещи совсем из другой.

Для это пользуйтесь Punto Switcher или аналогами

- [https://пунто-свитчер.рф/faq/analog-windows/](https://xn----dtbjlwgfofhfe4d.xn--p1ai/faq/analog-windows/)
- https://photolessons.org/en/langover/

---

Punto Switcher

> ### Возможности программы
>
> - Автоматическое переключение раскладки клавиатуры на нужный из двух заданных в настройках языков (по умолчанию — русский или английский,
>   но можно указать другую пару из установленных раскладок).
> - Ручное исправление ошибочно набранного выделенного текста либо последнего набранного слова при нажатии заданной пользователем горячей
>   клавиши.
> - Замена системного сочетания клавиш для ручного переключения раскладки.
> - Плавающий индикатор. Размещение языкового индикатора в любом месте экрана.
> - Назначение или отмена опций автопереключения и автоисправления для выбранных пользователем программ.
> - Перевод русскоязычного текста в [транслит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82) и обратно.
> - Преобразование числа в текст. Замена выделенного числа или денежной суммы, написанных цифрами, на число или сумму прописью. Позволяет
>   заменить, например, 247-23 на «Двести сорок семь рублей 23 копейки».
> - Отображение индикатора текущей раскладки в системном лотке в виде флагов.
> - Оповещение звуком о переключении раскладки, своё озвучивание нажатий клавиш для каждой раскладки клавиатуры.
> - Автозамена текста по заранее заданным в программе шаблонам, например, «дд» можно автоматически заменять на «Добрый день!».
> - Исправление наиболее часто встречающихся опечаток, например, «очепятка» на «опечатка» (опция существовала в одной из промежуточных
>   версий). В настоящее время опция не поддерживается, но пользователь
>   сам может создать в разделе «Автозамена» список исправления опечаток.
> - Очистка текста от форматирования при его копировании и вставке. Для активизации опции необходимо назначить для неё «горячую клавишу».
> - Проверка допустимости сочетания букв для текущего языка в набираемом тексте, звуковое оповещение при обнаружении языковых аномалий.
> - Просмотр, сохранение в файл [буфера обмена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) Windows, хранение
>   до 30 буферов обмена.
> - Ведение дневника — сохранение всех текстов, набираемых на клавиатуре (опционально), также сохранение выделенного текста в дневник по
>   горячей клавише.
> - Горячие клавиши для поиска выделенного на экране текста: «Найти в Яндексе»,
>   «[Яндекс.Словарях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8)», «В
>   [русской Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F)»,
>   «В [английской
>   Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F)».
> - Отсылка разработчикам по [эл. почте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0) новых
>   предложений по комбинации преобразуемых символов.
> - Отправка текста в [Твиттер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) из любого приложения.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_Switcher